# Multi-Level grouping aggregate with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have project we are working for, and I have chart of account built with multi-level parent/children

ex.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e0",
        "name": "Cash",
        "code": "1",
        "codeChain": "1",
        "isParent": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e1",
        "parent": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e0",
        "name": "Cash",
        "code": "01",
        "codeChain": "1.01",
        "isParent": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e2",
        "parent": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e1",
        "name": "Cash",
        "code": "001",
        "codeChain": "1.01.001",
        "isParent": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e3",
        "parent": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e2",
        "name": "Cash",
        "code": "001",
        "codeChain": "1.01.001.001",
        "isParent": true
    }
    // and so on
]
```

then we need to make a query to get the result of :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e0",
        "name": "Cash",
        "code": "1",
        "codeChain": "1",
        "isParent": true,
        "children": [
            {
                {
                    "_id": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e1",
                    "parent": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e0",
                    "name": "Cash",
                    "code": "01",
                    "codeChain": "1.01",
                    "isParent": true,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "_id": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e2",
                            "parent": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e1",
                            "name": "Cash",
                            "code": "001",
                            "codeChain": "1.01.001",
                            "isParent": true,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "_id": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e3",
                                    "parent": "6339dc11de91f060af6e17e2",
                                    "name": "Cash",
                                    "code": "001",
                                    "codeChain": "1.01.001.001",
                                    "isParent": true
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    // and so on
]
```

***NOTED THAT :*** We don't know how deep it could be, and also we have other collections with the transactions we will link it later

Or should we change all the data structure to serve that need !

Comment: `$graphLookup` might be a starting place, though I'm not sure if you'll be able to achieve the exact structure you want (with arbitrary nesting) directly from the database via a query/aggregation

Comment: So you think is it better to make it callback with await/async technique , by calling the first root and then call find children and add it to parents so on and then return the value .. !?

Comment: Yess either modify the data structure, or use the async await approach to find the children and populate the parents.